# How to extract list from Scheme program?

Tags: scheme, racket

I have been giving a language in Scheme.

```
(define-datatype statement statement?
  (add1 (V symbol?))
  (sub1 (V symbol?))
  (skip (V symbol?))
  (if-goto (V symbol?)
           (l symbol?)))

(define-datatype instruction instruction?
  (labeled (l symbol?)
           (i statement?))
  (unlabeled (i statement?)))

(define-datatype program program?
  (a-program (l (list-of instruction?))))
```

I am trying to create a new function which will be able to convert the program into a list of instructions. How would I go about doing this?

Here is what I have so far:

```
(define pgm->list
   (lambda (pgm)
     ;what goes here
```

Comment: `define-datatype` is not part of Scheme.  Can you describe it or axe the `scheme` tag?

Comment: Searching on `docs.racket-lang.org`, it seems `define-datatype` is part of both the `lang/htdp-advanced` and `eopl` modules. The OP should mention which book they're using.

Comment: If we assume that `pgm` is a `program` and a `program` contains a list of instructions, is the question simply how to access fields of the program data structure? Or are you interested in how to write a compiler?

Comment: There is also an egg in chicken sceme called datatype: A facility for creating and using variant records, as described in the book "Essentials of Programming Languages" by Friedman, Wand and Haynes.

Comment: @ramrunner yes this is the book I am working from. Sorry for not mentioning it, I didn't know this was specific to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sorry if this is wrong, if it is could you share a working implementation of your code?
i am really confused with

```
(define-datatype program program?
  (a-program (l (list-of instruction?))))
```

what is list-of? i should imagine here that you want to declare some variants of programs.
a-program would be defined as a list of instructions... ok. if list-of returns a lambda that is a correct predicate (that returns true only when acted on a list of instructions) then
does this work?

```
(define pgm->list
  (lambda (pgm)
    (cases program pgm
      (a-program (l) l))))
```

Edit : Since define-datatype was unknown to most of us except OP, i'm adding some documentation:

> **[syntax] (define-datatype TYPENAME [PREDICATE] VARIANT ...)**
>
> Defines a record type named TYPENAME, where VARIANT ... defines one or more
>   constructors for instances of this type. VARIANT should be of the form
>
> VARIANT = (CONSTRUCTOR (FIELDNAME FIELDPRED) ...)
>
> CONSTRUCTOR is the name of a constructor procedure that will be defined with as
>   many arguments as fields are specified. (FIELDNAME FIELDPRED) ... specify the name
>   for each field and a procedure of one argment that should return a true value for
>   legal field values.
>
> The optional PREDICATE should be the name of a procedure that will be defined and
>   which returns #t when applied to an instance of this variant record.
>
> **[syntax] (cases TYPENAME EXP CLAUSE ...)**
>
> A facility for matching and deconstructing the instance EXP of the variant record
>   with the name TYPENAME. Each CLAUSE specifies a constructor with field-names and
>   a body to execute when the constructor matches the record instance:
>
> CLAUSE = (CONSTRUCTOR (FIELDNAME ...) BODY ...)
>       | (else BODY ...)

cheers!

Comment: Helpful thanks! Now say I wanted to send the resulting list to another function, how would i go about doing that? When I try to modify the last line to something like: (other-func (a-program (l) l))))) I get an error saying the first l is now an unbound identifier

Comment: hmmm maybe i don't understand the question here. if other-func expects a list (of instructions) generated from a "program" then wouldn't that be (other-func (pgm->list program)) ? that seems trivial so please can you give us a working example to run it and figure it out ? :)  thanks dood!.

Comment: hmm i saw the thing about "last line". if you mean to change the last line of pgm->list code, that wouldn't work . you see the "cases" lambda unpacks the structure of program based on the type provided below. you have to use the whole if it as one closure. maybe you could create another lambda that uses the whole "pgm->list" to get the list and then send it to the other function as shown in the previous comment?

Comment: another quick question. Say I were trying to get the symbol out of the instruction how would I go about doing that? I am trying to follow the same format you gave me before and I have:(define instruction->sym
  (lambda (ins)
    (cases instruction ins
      (labeled (sym) sym)))) This of course doesn't work because labeled has 2 parameters. I can't seem to make the compiler accept anything with 2 parameters there. How should I be writing my syntax?

Comment: dood , i don't know the module and if you don't post some concrete example that i can run , i'm in the edge of my understanding :) . so just a wild guess here: labeled waits two parameters. so if you wrote your cases like  (cases instruction ins (labeled (sym stat) sym)  what would happen? here i guess that you say labeled awaits 2 fieds to be defined.

Comment: Well thanks for trying. I actually don't have anything more concrete sorry. I appreciate your efforts!